Getting Error while downloading ESim using DownloadableSubscription.forActivationCode
I am trying to download and install the eSim using DownloadableSubscription.forActivationCode in android but i am getting some weird error code.
I have search those in Android documentation as well but, luck.
Below are error codes that i am getting-
**ESim Result Code: 2 Error Code: 0
ESim Operation Code: 10 Detailed Code: 176316472
ESim Subject Code: 8.2.6 Reason Code: 3.8
**
Error Message: Result code for an operation indicating that an unresolvable error occurred.
I have implemented as per given in documentation. for more info refer:
Documentation
